# String replace not working or Im dumb?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have this:

```
for (String[] aZkratkyArray1 : zkratkyArray) {
    String oldString = " " + aZkratkyArray1[0] + " ";
    String firstString = aZkratkyArray1[0] + " ";
    String newString = " " + aZkratkyArray1[1] + " ";
    System.out.println(newString);
    System.out.println(fileContentsSingle);
    fileContentsSingle = fileContentsSingle.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
    if (fileContentsSingle.startsWith(firstString)) {
        fileContentsSingle = aZkratkyArray1[1] + " " + fileContentsSingle.substring(firstString.length(),fileContentsSingle.length());
    }
}
```

fileContentsSingle is just some regular string, aZkratkyArray is array with shortened words, f.e.:

- ht, hello there
- wru, who are you

So when fileContentsSingle = ht I am robot
it should end up : hello there I am robot

or when fileContentsSingle = I am robot hru
it should end up : I am robot who are you

But when I sysout fileContentsSingle after this iteration, or during it, string is never changed.

I tried both replace and replaceAll, I tried probably everything I could think of.

Where is the mistake?

EDIT:
This is how I import array:

```
        String[][] zkratkyArray;
        try {
            LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("zkratky.csv"));
            lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
            lineNumberReader.close();

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("zkratky.csv");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            zkratkyArray = new String[lines + 1][2];
            String line;
            int row = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] array = line.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    zkratkyArray[row][i] = array[i];
                }
                row++;
            }
            reader.close();
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Soubor se zkratkami nenalezen.");
            zkratkyArray = new String[0][0];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found out that I had BOM's in input.csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work correctly for "ht I am robot". If you print `fileContentsSingle` after your `for` loop, it will print what you expect it to print:

```
final String[][] zkratkyArray = new String[2][];
zkratkyArray[0] = new String[] { "ht", "hello there" };
zkratkyArray[1] = new String[] { "wru", "who are you" };

String fileContentsSingle = "ht I am robot";

for (String[] aZkratkyArray1 : zkratkyArray) {
    String oldString = " " + aZkratkyArray1[0] + " ";
    String firstString = aZkratkyArray1[0] + " ";
    String newString = " " + aZkratkyArray1[1] + " ";

    fileContentsSingle = fileContentsSingle.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
    if (fileContentsSingle.startsWith(firstString)) {
        fileContentsSingle = aZkratkyArray1[1] + " "
                + fileContentsSingle.substring(firstString.length(), fileContentsSingle.length());
    }
}

System.out.println(fileContentsSingle); // prints "hello there I am robot"
```

Concerning "I am robot hru", it will not work because "hru" is at the end of the `String`, and not followed by a space, and the `String` you are replacing is " hru " (with spaces before and after).

As you don't use regexps, you don't need [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)),  and you can use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead.

Using regexps, you can do a more generic solution working everywhere in the line:

```
final String[][] zkratkyArray = new String[2][];
zkratkyArray[0] = new String[] { "ht", "hello there" };
zkratkyArray[1] = new String[] { "wru", "who are you" };

String fileContentsSingle = "ht I am robot wru";

for (String[] aZkratkyArray1 : zkratkyArray) {
    fileContentsSingle = fileContentsSingle.replaceAll("\\b" + Pattern.quote(aZkratkyArray1[0]) + "\\b",
            Matcher.quoteReplacement(aZkratkyArray1[1]));
}

System.out.println(fileContentsSingle); // hello there I am robot who are you
```

Comment: @FilipKraus It works, see http://ideone.com/lBEnFl where I pasted the first block of code, it correctly prints "hello there I am robot".

Comment: I ment my code.

If I was about to use your code, could you help me to edit my input so it works for your code, please?

It would help me very much.

Comment: @FilipKraus And I even tested it with your CSV import code to fill the array, it still works. Are you sure that your CSV separator is "," ?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure, words are there like this:

shortcut,word
shortcut,word

so in the end there is comma and space after word

Comment: When I test sout on aZkratkyArray1[0] and [1] it really prints imported data like ht hellothere and next iteration wru = who are you, etc... but it doesn't replace anything.

Even with your code :
for (String[] aZkratkyArray1 : zkratkyArray) {
    fileContentsSingle = fileContentsSingle.replaceAll("\\b" + Pattern.quote(aZkratkyArray1[0]) + "\\b",
            Matcher.quoteReplacement(aZkratkyArray1[1]));
}

Comment: Isn't there any problem with my import code (I inserted it into question)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using any regex here. You are just reading a suustring and replace it with another one.

Just use the other version which does not use regex:

```
fileContentsSingle.replace(oldString, newString);
```

Comment: You mean `replace(String,String)`?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, that's what I mean.